# Case attachment not found via SOQL when added in community

Tags: soql, community, case, attachment

In a community (napili) there is a button (global action on case) that allow users to create a new case and add an attachment to this case.

When I do that, it creates me a case, and an attachment to this case. But in the developper console, if I try to access this attachment with a query like this in the query editor, it found nothing :

```
SELECT Id, ContentDocument.title, ContentDocument.ContentModifiedDate, 
                                    ContentDocument.FileExtension, ContentDocument.ContentSize, 
                                    ContentDocument.FileType, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId
                                    FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId ='5009E000007fay3QAA'
```

Also, if I add an attachment to a created case, via a lightning component with the tag `lightning:fileUpload`, when I try the query it works and retrieve the attachment.

Here is the attachment's list of a case, we can see that even if both are pdf, they are not display the same way :
[image]

Moreover, when I click the attachment in the attachment's list of a case, when it is the case added with the community it did not display the file, it only download it. Conversely when I click the attachment create by the lightning component, it display it like this : 
[image]

I need to get the attachments list of a case when the case is created, but as I said the query retrieve nothing when the attachment is added at the creation of the case.

Answer (score 2):

If thats an Attachment then your query will be

```
Select id,Name from Attachment where ParentID='5009E000007fay3QAA'
```

FileUpload doesnt create ContentDocument or ContentDocumentLink so you can just querry Attachment and get your job going.

Comment: I just try your query, and with it I can only get the attachment added with the community. It does not retrieve the file (or attachment ?) added with the lightning component via the tag `lightning:fileUpload`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use file instead of attachment ? It seems that when using the tag `lightning:fileUpload` it upload files, and when using the default uploading via the community it upload attachments...

Comment: Candidate for IdeaExchange.